# How to change position of inlineShapes in vb.net? (to output in word)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-word

I'm trying to add the logo at the top right corner of a word doc, but i can´t.
I tried Mr.Goggle but i wasn't able to find the answer.
Please i'm desperate. HELP!

```
 oPara(1) = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        oPara(1).Range.Text = "Text"
        oPara(1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\logo.png")
        oPara(1).Range.InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleWidth = 20
        oPara(1).Range.InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleHeight = 20
        oPara(1).Range.InlineShapes.Item(1) ?? <---
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Inline shapes have `Left` and `RelativeHorizontalPosition` properties. Have you tried either of those? Also, if you're trying to put something in the top right corner of the page, the header section might be more appropriate than the body's paragraphs because the top bound of the page body lies a bit below the actual top of the page.

Comment: yes I tried, but they dont appear in auto complete, so I thought that was not it. I'll try

Comment: Is your goal to add the logo to the top right corner of the page in the header, or are you trying to display it in-line with the document's text around it?

Comment: I'm trying to add at the top right corner Example: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RXNkFiUpm-IdvvxQoGnlvxc9fc45RZNH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding it as a Shape instead of InlineShape. That gives you a few more properties to control its positioning, and you can get the effect of an inline shape by setting the Shape's WrapFormat.Type:

```
Dim logoFilepath As String = "C:\logo.png"
Dim sampleText As String = ""
For i As Integer = 0 To 200
    sampleText &= "sample text "
Next

Dim oApp As Word.Application = New Word.Application
oApp.Visible = True
Dim oDoc As Word.Document = oApp.Documents.Add
Dim oPara As Word.Paragraph = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
oPara.Range.Text = sampleText
Dim oShape As Word.Shape = oDoc.Shapes.AddPicture(logoFilepath, False, True)
With oShape
    .RelativeHorizontalPosition = Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
    .Left = Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeRight
    .WrapFormat.Type = Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapSquare 'wdWrapTopBottom if you want the text below the logo
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, thanks for all the help, i manage to make myself a solution with all the advices you gave me. So i made aa new paragraph and set the alignmen to the right :)
like this:

```
        oPara(0) = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        oPara(0).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:="C:\Users\"user"\"folder"\logo.png")
        oPara(0).Range.InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleWidth = 20
        oPara(0).Range.InlineShapes.Item(1).ScaleHeight = 20
        oPara(0).Format.SpaceAfter = 0
        oPara(0).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphRight

        oPara(1) = oDoc.Content.Paragraphs.Add
        oPara(1).Range.Text = "Text"
        oPara(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
        oPara(1).Range.Font.Color = RGB(0, 85, 81)
        oPara(1).Range.Font.Size = 16
        oPara(1).Format.SpaceAfter = 0
        oPara(1).Range.InsertParagraphAfter()
```